# Postfix email throttling for deferred queue

Tags: postfix, email-bounces, rate-limiting

I have an issue with email sending speeds on postfix. the email to yahoo are getting throttled and getting suspended temporarily. I edited the main.cf configuration to slower down the speeds and add a delay. This works fine with email sending at delay but i have a problem here. the mails which are there in deferred or retry queue, when they are sent, they are sent a very high speed and throttles the connection. is there a way to control deferred queue speed on postfix.

Comment: You might just be getting grey-listed by the Yahoo server. Have you been sending email to Yahoo before, or is this is a relatively new SMTP deployment? Additionally, you should check your domain/configuration with something like mxtoolbox.

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes, i know the grey listing  part, that is the reason i send emails with a delay which works fine. However when i see the emails which are in deferred queue, when they retry, the postfix delayed configuration is not applied to them. they are sent almost instantly. I want to know how to control postfix retry attempt speed